# Why when I change disable to readonly, only one input field cannot modified. The other input field still available

Tags: javascript, html

I change disable function to readonly as when I select cash, and submit the form, there is an error because is no data insert. But after I change disable to readonly, when I select cash, only input field icpayer is disabled. And the others input field are not. Why this problem occur ?

Before:

```
if( $(this).val() == 'cash') {
        $('#payername').prop( "disabled", true );
        $('#icpayer').prop( "disabled", true );
        $('#panelname').prop( "disabled", true );
}else {       
        $('#payername').prop( "disabled", false );
        $('#icpayer').prop( "disabled", false );
        $('#panelname').prop( "disabled", false );}
```

After:

```
if( $(this).val() == 'cash') {
        $('#payername').prop( "readonly", true );
        $('#icpayer').prop( "readonly", true );
        $('#panelname').prop( "readonly", true );
}else {       
        $('#payername').prop( "readonly", false );
        $('#icpayer').prop( "readonly", false );
        $('#panelname').prop( "readonly", false );}
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-01">
  <label for="billingtype"><b>Billing Type :</b></label>
 </div>
 <div class="col-02">
  <select id="billingtype" name="billingtype">
   <option value="">Select</option>
   <option value="cash">Cash</option>
    <option value="card">Card</option>
   </select>
  </div>

 <div class="col-01">
  <label for="icno"><b>IC No :</b></label>
 </div>
                                        
 <div class="col-02">
  <div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" id = "icpayer" name="icpayer" class="form-control">
 </div> 
</div>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-01">
  <label for="name"><b>Payer Name :</b></label>
 </div>
 <div class="col-02">
  <input type="text" id="payername" name="payername" >                  
 </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-01">
  <label for="name"><b>Panel Name :</b></label>
 </div>
 <div class="col-02">
   <input type="text" id="panelname" name="panelname" >                  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML? The property name is `disabled` and not `disable`. Maybe in your HTML if you the disabled property name set for that specific input field.

Comment: Hi, i already update my code above. I write it back, so I mispelled the disabled.

Comment: In your code, what does `$(this).val()` refer to? What element does it point to? If it is a <select>element, then your code might not work properly. While working with<select> you should check the value of the "selected" option, so - `$(this).find('option:selected').val() == 'cash'`

Comment: Yes, it refer to select element. I already update the HTML code above. I tried as you suggested, but it still disabled icpayer field only. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: I am not sure what you tried since the JavaScript code in your question does not show the complete version. I'm adding a working fiddle link to the answer section. If you have any queries, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Below is how the JavaScript code should be, I am assuming you changed the code after our discussion. But please do compare once.

```
$('#billingtype').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).find('option:selected').val() == 'cash') {
    $('#payername').prop("readonly", true);
    $('#icpayer').prop("readonly", true);
    $('#panelname').prop("readonly", true);
  } else {
    $('#payername').prop("readonly", false);
    $('#icpayer').prop("readonly", false);
    $('#panelname').prop("readonly", false);
  }
});
```

Here's a working fiddle for your reference. All the input fields are set to `readonly` as expected. I add basic CSS to visually change the style when the input field becomes readonly.

https://jsfiddle.net/xbrqtuzm/

Remember, a `readonly` form field can still be clicked and focused.

Comment: Hi sir. Thank you for your help. I tried your suggestion by point the selected option. But it still didn't work for me. When I tried to write my code back in the fiddle, it works. But when I code it in my VSC, the same problem still occur where only icpayer field disabled and the other fields are not. Do you have any idea why this problem occur ? I tried to check my html code and any parentheses that I miss, but everything seems fine to me. Thank you in advance for your help, sir :)

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with the code. It might be something in your IDE or some hidden code that you are not aware of. Find me on gitter.im and we can debug it together.